# Visual Studio 2010 Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I 've had a list of Visual Studio 2008 keyboard shortcuts pinned to my wall for quite some time - http://nerdfortress.s3.amazonaws.com/visual-studio-2008-keyboard-shortcuts.html.

Does anyone know of a similar thing for Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Here is the link which provide keyboard and mouse shortcuts of visual studio 2010 http://geekswithblogs.net/ToStringTheory/archive/2012/06/06/visual-studio-2010-productivity-tips-and-tricks-part-2-key-shortcuts.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scott Guthrie j[ust posted about this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/30/april-30th-links-asp-net-asp-net-mvc-visual-studio-2010.aspx). You can download a list of shortcuts directly from Microsoft at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=92ced922-d505-457a-8c9c-84036160639f

Comment: Ah, "Keybinding Cards".  I would not have thought to call them this.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few links you could try:

http://www.devcurry.com/2010/04/visual-studio-2010-keyboard-shortcuts.html

http://www.itscodingtime.com/post/Visual-Studio-2010-Keyboard-Mouse-Shortcuts.aspx

The devcurry.com site shows the nicer PDF version from Microsoft.